# Understanding HTML vs VUE file strategy with Vue apps

Tags: vue.js

New to Vue and trying to understand exactly what things need to be pages (`.html` files) and which things need to be Vue components (`.vue` files). I understand that Vue components are meant to be reusable, but let's say I have a Log In screen which is the "entry point" to my web app.

The Log In screen doesn't need to be dynamic, can display the same for everyone, and doesn't need to be reusable.

So would I make a `public/login.html` file or would I make a `src/components/Login.vue` file? And why?

If I just make a `public/login.html` file, does Vue provide any JavaScript APIs that I could place inside the `<script>` tags to make my life easier (say, for submitting the login form), or is it standard to just use other JS frameworks like jQuery for this type of stuff?

And if I should make it an actual component (`src/components/Login.vue` file), then whats the general rule for knowing when to make an HTML page and when to make it a VUE component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need at least one HTML file per page. You can think it is a master layout of the page. In case of SPA usually you will need only one HTML due to the application will navigate itself inside a placeholder without asking the server for a new HTML.

Inside each HTML you can decide which part of the page to create as a Vue component. If the page is not dynamic then you don't need Vue for that page. If it is dynamic but it is easier to do with jQuery then you don't need Vue.

Comment: I guess here's a better way of looking at my question: what do I **gain** by making my Login page a Vue component?

Comment: Meaning: lets say I've already decided to make this a Vue application, that's not up for question. But what about this particular scenario. Does my Login page need to be a Vue component? If not, can I do HTML with a `<script>` tag that uses Vue inside of it for submitting the form? Or in Vue is _everything_ supposed to be a component and you just accept that fact, even if the "component" is a page that will never be reused anywhere else?

Comment: Or are you saying that I create one HTML (for an SPA) and then use Vue/JS to display only one Vue component at a time (so: Login component, Dashboard component, AccountSettings component, etc.)?

Comment: You can use Vue in two ways. As a JavaScript library like jQuery or SPA. You can think a Vue component is a DOM element like `div` etc. In case of SPA usually there will be only one `div` inside a `body` that will be mounted as a Vue component. Then you use Vue Router to dynamically update the content of that component.

Comment: You can find the example code in the getting started page on it official website. It should be straightforward enough to easy understand.